# Value of r (intrinsic rate of natural increase)

Tags: ecology, population-dynamics, population-biology, demography

What is the current value of 'r' (instrinsic rate of natural increase) in India? How do we calculate it?

My book says that In 1981, the r value for human population in India was 0.0205. But this link (https://www.google.co.in/amp/knoema.com/atlas/India/topics/Demographics/Population/Rate-of-natural-increase%3fmode=amp) says it was around 22.50 in the year 1981. Such big discrepancies are a query.

Comment: Perhaps you should check the census report. You should add details to your question and be clear about what you are asking. [Edit] the question to add all necessary details. Comments should be used for asking clarification.

Comment: About the value of 22.5 (in your question); that is referring to a growth of 22.5 persons per one thousand population. So a growth of 2,3% (22.5/1000= 0.0225).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [UN database](https://esa.un.org/unpd/wpp/DVD/) (this info is also reported on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India)), the growth rate in India in 2016 was $r=1.019$.

It is computed as $r = \frac{N_{2017}}{N_{2016}}$, where $N_{y}$ is the population size at year $y$. This estimate is based on the total number of residents (regardless of their legal status).

**More explanations**

$r$ is simply defined as $r = \frac{N_{2017}}{N_{2016}}$. Often, you will read statistics in the sense of percentage of increase. Let's call this value $x$. $x$ is then defined as $1+x = r$.

It is just like when you put money in a bank account. If your interest rate is $x = 2\% = 0.02$, then if you had $N_{2010} = 1000$ dollars in 2010, in 2011, you'll have $$N_{2011} = 1000 + 1000 * 0.02 = (1+0.02) * 1000$$. Note that $1+0.02 = 1 + x = r$. Over $k$ years, you'll have $$N_{2010+k} = N_{2010} (1+0.02)^k$$.

Comment: My book says that r is calculated as birth rate minus death rate, and calculating it through the values mentioned on the internet, it shows big discrepancies!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India Considering Wikipedia, the birth rate minus death rates comes out to be 11.

Comment: Per 1000 individuals, yes. Divide 11 by 1000 and you get $0.011$, which means $N_{2016} = N_{2017} + N_{2017} * 0.011$, which can be rewritten $N_{2016} = (1 + 0.011) \cdot  N_{2017}$, hence $r = 1.011$, which is pretty close to $r=1.019$. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Do we always take the original population size as 1 for a year, while calculating this rate?

Comment: I don't really understand this follow-up question. But please see edit.

Comment: You calculation is of lambda ($\lambda$), not $r$ (instrinsic rate of increase), where $r$ is $ln(\lambda)$.

Answer (score 4):

NCERT shows per capita value is divided by 1000, not hundred (%). So the data you see is 22.50 per thousand! So, the per capita rate is 22.50/1000 = 0.02250 that is almost equal to 0.0205 given in book!

To make you understand better, remember that GDP and per capita GDP is different, the same way birth rate or death rate is calculated per 1000 but when we ask per capita we have to actually divide it by 1000.

Now in 2016 , it is 0.01019 i.e. 0.0102

I hope you understand!!

Answer (score 2):

It the most basic form, the intrinsic rate of increase, $r$, is defined as:

$\frac{dN}{dt} = rN = (a-b)N$

where $a$ is the birth rate per unit time and $b$ is the death rate per unit time. So $r$ is the birth rate minus the death rate. The modell can naturally also be extended to e.g. include carrying capacity or to make $r$ (or underlying parameters) functions of time or environmental variables.

However, from census data (taken at fixed points in time), you can calculate lambda ($\lambda$), the discrete-time per capita growth rate (also called the *finite rate of increase*), as:

$\frac{N_{t+1}}{N_t} = \lambda$

This shows the growth across a fixed, discrete time intervall. $\lambda$ can  be converted to an instantaneous instrinsic rate of increase as $r = log(\lambda)$. Using the values in Remi.b's answer (from https://esa.un.org/unpd/wpp/DVD/), this yields and $r$ of 0.0188 (i.e. log(1.019)). For a bit more background see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_dynamics and http://www.zo.utexas.edu/courses/thoc/PopGrowth.html (or any textbook on population dynamics).

Answer (score -3):

[image]
Population growth curved à when responses are not limitting the growth , plot is exponential , b when response are limitting the growth , plot is logistic , k carrying capacity

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP's questions, which is specifically about the *value* of r for a particular population (humans in India)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. If you can address the problems noted in the above comments, please also provide a citation/source for the image you are using — images should be credited to their creators just like [quotes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) are to their authors. This is generally considered good practice in scientific communication and will help other users by providing context. ——— If you are unwilling or unable to fix these issues, please delete your post. Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for more advice on [Answer] effectively on this site.